# What will be bytes occupied if we store 2 bytes value in 8 bytes column?

Tags: postgresql

There is one column which has the column (Column A) type as bigint(8 bytes), and I am storing the value in smallint(2 bytes). Since I may store bigint value in Column A so defined the data type as bigint.

What will be bytes taken the particular column contains smallint value? 8 bytes or 2 bytes.

Also, there is one column (Column B) which has column type as Varchar(100), and if I trying to store a value with length 50. What will be size occupied by the column? size of varchar(100) or size of varchar(50).

PS: I am using postgres for database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily get the values you are after:

```
SELECT column_a, pg_column_size(column_a), 
       column_b, pg_column_size(column_b), 
       ... 
  FROM your_table;
```

This gives you the byte size of the given values stored in the columns, alongside with the values themselves.

A `bigint` will always consume 8 bytes, whereas a `varchar` just the size needed for the given value.  (The latter is tricky, read upon [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html).)

Comment: It will help I think if you add an example for varchar. Say varchar(50) may need 50*M bytes (where M is the max number of bytes per character, 4 I think) + 1 (or 4) bytes, for storing the byte length (0-200).